# Draw a line between div's using ngFor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<div class="block" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <p>Hey</p>
</div>
```

I've an `ngFor` directive like above. Now, I want to draw a straight line between the items rendered by the directive. All the sample code I've seen tries doing this between two static `div`'s using `svg` or `canvas`. Is there a simple way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Include `border-bottom` property in your "block" CSS selector.

```
.block {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufncjj)

**Update:**

If you would not like to add it to the "block" selector, include an additional selector as shown below. Also since it is a divider between `div` components you could also remove the line after the last `div`.

Template:

```
<div class="block" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; last as isLast">
  <p>Hey</p>
  <div *ngIf="!isLast">
    <div class="divider"><div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divider {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztmmar)

Answer (score 0):

Consider CSS approach.

You can draw lines between elements excluding the last one using `:not` and `:last-child` selector.

```css
.block:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Hey</p>
  </div>
</div>
```